# Why are the tables in minipages left out of the list of tables?

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, minipage

I have some tables inside of `minipage` enviroment but they don't appear listed like the others in my `\listoftables`; see the code below.

```
\listoftables
.
.
.
\begin{table}   
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c}    %This one is classify
...
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{minipage}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c}    %This one isn't classify
...
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither `table`, `tabular` or `minipage` add something to the list of tables. This is done by `\caption` inside `table` or `\captionof{table}` (package `caption` or `capt-of`).

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
  \listoftables
  \newpage

  \begin{table}
    \caption{First table}
    \begin{tabular}{l}
      foo\\bar
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}

  \noindent
  \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \captionof{table}{Second table}
    \begin{tabular}{l}
      foo\\bar
    \end{tabular}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \captionof{table}{Third table}
    \begin{tabular}{l}
      foo\\bar
    \end{tabular}
  \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: How did you get this nice shaded box?

Comment: @Jubobs: I "misuse" the quoting feature for this: `> ![Result][1]`.

Comment: Ah, you fooled me!